# How do I make a heatmap-style bivariate histogram in a lattice layout?

Tags: r, lattice

Take the following example data:

```
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000) * x
z <- rnorm(10000) * y
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

We can produce a scatter plot matrix as follows:

```
splom(df)
```

[image]

But due to the large number of overlapping points it is hard to gauge the density.

Is there a straightforwards way to replace each plot with a bivariate histogram heatmap, like those produced by [squash](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/squash/)?

```
library(squash)
hist2(df$x, df$y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `panel.hexbinplot` is convenient for large datasets.

```
library(hexbin)
splom(df, panel=panel.hexbinplot)
```

[image]

You can customize the panel function like this :

```
library(hexbin)
splom(df,
      panel = function(x, y, ...){
        panel.hexbinplot(x, y, style = "nested.lattice", 
                      type = c("g", "smooth"),col='blue', ...)
      },
      pscale=0, varname.cex=0.7)
```

You can play with teh `style` parameter.

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising, but I get the following error: 
    Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_downviewport, name$name, strict) : 
      Viewport 'plot_01.panel.1.1.off.vp' was not found

Comment: @saffsd it is strange. Try to it in a new R session please.

Comment: The error persists in a new session. For reference: R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: @saffsd I can't test it on a linux version now. But on windows it works.

Comment: The problem is with the type=XXX argument, removing that produces a working plot.

Comment: the type "g" to add grill, and smooth to get the blue line...but all this are optional regarding your question..

Answer (score 4):

here's another option that's more in-line with your original request

```
# run the code you've provided
library(lattice)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000) * x
z <- rnorm(10000) * y
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# look at each of these options one-by-one..  go slowly!

# here's your original
splom(df)


# here each point has been set to very transparent
splom(df , col="#00000005" )
```

[image]

```
# here each point has been set to moderately transparent
splom(df , col="#00000025" )
```

[image]

```
# here each point has been set to less transparent
splom(df , col="#00000050" )
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good idea to make the points smaller as well, e.g. `splom(df , col="#00000040", pch = '.' )`.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't the method you asked for, but does help you solve the fundamental issue you've described  :)

```
# run the code you've provided
library(lattice)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000) * x
z <- rnorm(10000) * y
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# figure out what ten percent of the total records are
ten.percent <- nrow( df ) / 10

# create a new data frame `df2` containing
# a randomly-sampled ten percent of the original data frame
df2 <- df[ sample( nrow( df ) , ten.percent  ) , ]

# now `splom` that.. and notice it's easier to see densities
splom(df2)
```